# Kick all command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I need a kick all command for terminating server in a fun way

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick_all(ctx):
    while True:
        for server_member in ctx.message.server.members:
            try:
                channel = bot.get_channel('540612578401976330')
                await bot.kick(server_member)
                await bot.send_message(channel, "someone got kicked")
            except discord.Forbidden:
                pass
```

Output:

```
Ignoring exception in command kick_all
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adamk\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/adamk/PycharmProjects/bot/Server_KillSwitch.py", line 18, in kick_all
    for server_member in ctx.message.server.members:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adamk\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 846, in process_commands
    yield from command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\adamk\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 374, in invoke
    yield from injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\adamk\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 54, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the list as you do it, and raising an error. Use

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def kick_all(ctx):
    members = ctx.message.server.members.copy();
    while True:
        for server_member in members:
            try:
                channel = bot.get_channel('540612578401976330')
                await bot.kick(server_member)
                await bot.send_message(channel, "someone got kicked")
            except discord.Forbidden:
                pass
```

Comment: You'll get the same exception because `members = ctx.message.server.members` _does not copy_ `ctx.message.server.members`, so you'll still be iterating over this same dictionary while deleting items from it. Here's a simplified version of your code that errors out as well: `D = {str(i):i for i in range(10)}; not_a_copy=D; [D.popitem() for _ in not_a_copy]`.

Comment: @ForceBru Fixed it

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're deleting items from `ctx.message.server.members` *while iterating over it*, which is not allowed, and doesn't make much sense either: what's the next element doing to be after you deleted an element previous to the current one? or the next one? or the current one?

You can quickly fix this by iterating over a copy of the dictionary:

```
for server_member in ctx.message.server.members.copy():
    ...  # your code here
```